# working with 1m faces mesh. how to uv map/unwrap?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

im new to blender and dindt get into uv mapping jet. what im trying to do is uv map an landscape that has 1million faces. apart from uv mapping, just assigning my image wont work cause it is the wrong size (a bit too big). as far as i understand uv mapping helps me assign my image and cutting off what i dont need. so i want to ask: is it even possible to uv map/unwrap such a big mesh? and if so how to? or are there better ways to do that?

thanks for all answers.
-laurin

edit: i tried mesh>cleanup>limited dissolve in edit mode to reduce myface amount. i think my pc cant handle that. blender goes unresponsive (for 10 min now)

Comment: Hi, welcome. Your question is not that much clear and easy to understand, imho. Do you wish to know how to UV map in general, or how to reduce the mesh complexity? To handle million-faces meshes, you need a very good computer setup, anyway. But it seems you have very little experience with UV mapping, I suggest to learn with simpler setups, and only later handle huge sets of faces. You can't get a full tutorial here, just answers to questions. Simpler and clearer questions get easiest and better answers. An if you can add an image of the setup, at least, it always helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. after the comment of m.ardito i tried uv mapping with easier stuff. after i knew the basics i did my landscape again (using heightmap) with fewer faces. then i could unwrap it and assign my texture to it. after that i didsubdivide smooth a few times to get to an hihger detail grade.

no need to answer anymore.

sadly i cant accept my own answer right now. gotta wait 2 days.